# How to add gaussian noise to an image in the frequency domain using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, fft

I'm new to image processing and I'm wondering how to add a gaussian noise to grayscale image in the frequency domain. I know how to do this in the spatial domain.

```py
import imageio
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mean = 50
var = 50
sigma = var ** 0.5

image = imageio.imread('Pictures/Picture.jpg')
noisy_image = np.copy(image)

for i in range(image.shape[0]):
    for j in range(image.shape[1]):
        noisy_image[i][j] += np.random.normal(mean, sigma, (1,1))

figure, a = plt.subplots(1,2)
a[0].imshow(image, cmap='gray')
a[0].set_title('original image')
a[1].imshow(noisy_image, cmap='gray')
a[1].set_title('noisy image')
plt.show()
```

But when I try the same process in the frequency domain it won't work.

```py
import imageio
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mean = 50
var = 50
sigma = var ** 0.5

image = imageio.imread('Pictures/Picture.jpg')
noisy_image = np.copy(image)

# transformation to the frequency domain
noisy_image = np.fft.fft2(noisy_image)

for i in range(image.shape[0]):
    for j in range(image.shape[1]):
        noisy_image[i][j] += np.complex(np.random.normal(mean, sigma, (1,1)))

# transformation back to the spatial domain
image_noisy = np.real(np.fft.ifft2(image_noisy))

figure, a = plt.subplots(1,2)
a[0].imshow(image, cmap='gray')
a[0].set_title('original image')
a[1].imshow(noisy_image, cmap='gray')
a[1].set_title('noisy image')
plt.show()
```

Comment: getting this error when I run your top most code in spatial domain     "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "add_noise_to_picture_time_domain.py", line 18, in <module>
    noisy_image[i][j] += np.random.normal(mean, sigma, (1,1))
numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: Cannot cast ufunc 'add' output from dtype('float64') to dtype('uint8') with casting rule 'same_kind'
"

Comment: Instead of:

```for i in range(image.shape[0]):
    for j in range(image.shape[1]):
        noisy_image[i][j] += np.complex(np.random.normal(mean, sigma, (1,1)))```

you should consider using the following, it is much more efficient then looping over every single pixel:

```noisy_image += sigma * np.random.randn(noisy_image.shape[0], noisy_image.shape[1]) + mean```

Comment: Can you explain what output you expect from your code?

Comment: I want to have an image with gaussian noise and I want to add this noise in the frequency domain instead of the spatial domain.